# What to return if checked exception occurs?

Tags: java, exception

I wonder what should be returned, when some exception occurs as like in my example

```
public MyClass createComponent(){
  String className = "foo.MyClass";
  try {
    final Class<? extends MyClass> clazz = Class.forName(className).asSubclass(MyClass.class);
    return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(List.class, String.class).newInstance(list, name);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
// return null; //??  
}
```

Comment: That depends on that what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the logic of your API and the likeness of the root exception you may

- return `null`
- rethrow the exception
- let it pass (i.e. declare and don't catch)
- throw a new exception, embedding the cause

If the exceptions are really exceptional (they should not occur) as seems from your code, you probably should throw a runtime exception or a `InternalError` stating that there's an internal error in your library. Returning `null` here would do nothing good and might hide a bug.

Comment: +1 If you have no idea what to do with the Exception, re-throw it or declare it in the method `throws` clause. If it is an Exception which you are assuming is impossible, I would wrap it with `throw new AssettionError(e);`

Comment: I would definitely add "don't catch it in the first place" (just declare it) as an option.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is that desirable when there are so many possible exceptions ?

Comment: @dystroy: Possibly not in the example given, but that's only an example - in *many* other cases there are far fewer checked exceptions involved, and simply letting it propagate is more appropriate. That's very often the right approach for IOException, for example.